# Finding and Looping Through span Elements Inside (this) JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to find every `<span class ="anime_yellow">..` inside another `<span class="toggle">`, this is the code:

HTML:

```
    <span class="title_white">Menu 1</span>
      <span class="toggle">
     this is menu 1 i want to animate
          <span id="position" class="anime_yellow">Position</span>
        and
          <span id ="market" class="anime_yellow">market</span>.
      </span>
    <br><br>

    <span class="title_white">Menu 2</span>
      <span class="toggle">
     this is menu 2 i want to animate
          <span id="simple" class="anime_yellow">Simple</span>
        and
          <span id ="kool" class="anime_yellow">Kool</span>.
      </span>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(".toggle").hide();
$(".title_white").click(function() {
        $(".toggle").hide();
        $(this).next(".toggle").toggle("slow");
        // i want to find every span.anime_yellow inside the
        // THIS TOGGLE class and get its element ID
        // and then run function on the ID
        // animate(position) or animate(simple).

      });
```

im trying to use the jquery function .find(), but don't know where to start, this is the jsfiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wJJBa/2/

Comment: can you not just use $(this ".anime_yellow")???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/sZUAE/1/

```
function animate(divID) {
    alert(divID);
}

$(".toggle").hide();
$(".title_white").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").hide();
    var $toggle = $(this).next(".toggle");
    $toggle.toggle("slow");
    $toggle.find(".anime_yellow").each(function(i, e) {
        animate(e.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is really good, but i already have a function called animate(divId), which deos some animation for me, i just need get the id of each anime_yellow class

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wJJBa/5/ can u try this please, i dnt think the id is being passed to the function, +1 upvote from me :)

Comment: my mistake: `e` is an HTML element so you get its `id` with `.id` and your mistake: you have to define the animate function before using it :)

Answer (score 2):

Edited with your Code Sample:

```
$(".toggle").hide();
$(".title_white").click(function() {
  $(".toggle").hide();
  var $toggle = $(this).next(".toggle");
  $toggle.toggle("slow");
  $toggle.find(".anime_yellow").each(function (i, e) {
    animate($(this).attr("id")); //Your ID is HERE
  });
});
function animate(divID){    
  alert(divID);
}
```

Comment: how can i get the element id for each span.anime_yellow

Comment: I added more code, the syntax may not be perfect, but I believe should get you the ID you are looking for and point you in the right direction.